# Why is power dissipated in a circuit maximum when external resistance is equal to the internal resistance in the circuit?

Tags: electric-current, power

[image: qu]`[![question 24][1]][1]`[image: 2nd page][image: derivation for maximum current]Suppose in a circuit the battery has emf 6V and internal resistance 3ohm. It is connected to an external resistance = R ohm. According to my book the maximum power dissipated is when R = 3 ( I.e. internal resistance). They have derived the result and it seems fine. Now power = I^2 ( R+3) and I = 6/(R + 3) so power should be 36/(R+3). But if we put R=3 power is 6 w and if we put R = 0 power is 12 w. So shouldn't power be maximum when external resistance is 0?

Comment: I suspect the book means that the maximum power dissipated **in the load $R$** is when $R=3$. If you set $R=0$ then the power dissipated in $R$ is obviously zero, and if you set $R=\infty$ the power dissipated in $R$ is obviously zero. So the maximum of the power dissipated in $R$ is somewhere in between. With a bit of algebra you can easily show the maximum is at $R=3$.

Comment: I made a mistake actually. According to my book current is maximum when external resistance = internal resistance. But since power =I^2R, power will also be maximum when current is maximum.  The question says power dissipated in circuit and not in R @john Rennie

Comment: The book considers only components "external" to the power supply to be the circuit... or it is poorly phrased.

Comment: Current is a maximum when $R_\text{ext}=0$ not when $R_\text{ext}=R_\text{int}$.

Comment: I am posting the proof given in my book.

Comment: I think the book is talking about how to arrange multiple cells in order to improve output. And it considers the load resistance constant. Quite different than what we assumed your question was about.

Comment: I am posting the original question, please tell me what would be the case in this.

Answer (score 4):

Your confusion is between two related concepts.

1. Power dissipated in total = internal power + external power. If that is the power you are talking about, then an external short circuit will maximize the current and therefore maximize total power, $V\cdot I$.
2. Power delivered to the load. That is the thing addressed by the maximum power transfer theorem, and it requires internal resistance = external resistance.

The proof follows simply. If we have internal resistance $R_i$ and external resistance $R_o$, then the total resistance is $R_i+R_o$. The current is $\frac{V}{R_i+R_o}$ and the voltage across the external resistor is current times resistance. It follows that power in the external resistor is $\frac{V}{R_i+R_o}\frac{V\cdot R_o}{R_i+R_o}$

To find the maximum of that power, we take the derivative w.r.t $R_o$ and set it to zero:

$$\begin{align}\frac{dP}{d(R_o)}\propto \frac{-2R_o}{\left(R_i+R_o\right)^3}+\frac{1}{\left(R_i+R_o\right)^2}&=0\implies\\
-2R_o+R_i+R_o&=0\implies\\
R_o&=R_i\end{align}$$

Comment: Thanks, now I understand the concept of power dissipation. But I don't understand in a circuit why is the current maximum when external resistance = internal resistance?

Comment: The current is not maximum; the power dissipation in the external load is.

Comment: I am posting  the proof given in my book

Comment: Moreover if we just say that external resistance = internal resistance -1, and for a moment we don't consider the prove, then the power would be more than the power when external resistance = internal resistance. Isn't it? @Floris

Comment: I think you made a mistake, when we do $\frac{d(R + R_o)^{-2}}{d(R_o)}$, we apply chain rule , which is not been applied by you here.

Comment: @maverick I think I did it right. Can you tell me how the result should look according to you?

Comment: @Floris well, I myself came searching for answer, and I did the same thing that you have done, but stumbled upon the chain rule and I am getting $2 R R_i = R +R_i$

Comment: @Floris When you did this step $R_o \frac{d(R_i + R_o)^{-2}}{d(R_o)}$, I got  $-2 \frac{R_i R_o}{(R_i +R_o)^{-3}}$, I applied the chain rule of derivatives, correct me if I am wrong I am not a mainstream maths student, but these were the basics which I learnt

Comment: See [this link](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=d%28x%20%2F%28a%2Bx%29%5E2%29%2Fdx) for a basic derivation - I simplified the notation to $R_0=x$ and $R=a$ but the result is the same.